# How can I fix not printing out the correct thing the assignment wants me to print?

Tags: python

I have an assignment where I have to use dictionaries to make a "phone book".

I have already tried rewatching the video and trial and error for about an hour with no change.

My code:

```py
phone_book = {}

while True:
    name = input("Enter a name: ")

    if name in phone_book:
        print(phone_book[name])
    elif name == "":
        break
    else:
        phone_number = input("Enter a phone number in the following format[(123)456-7890)]: ")
        phone_book[name] = phone_number

    print(phone_book)
```

The check code for assignment requirements says:

1. You should print the final dictionary. Make sure you print out the dictionary directly(don't iterate through it)

expected result:

```py
Phone number: 1234
Phone number: 5678
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
```

my result:

```py
{'Karel': '1234'}
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234'}
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
1234
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
5678
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
```

2. You should print the phone number for names who already exist in the dictionary

your result:

```py
{'Karel': '1234'}
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234'}
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
1234
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
5678
{'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have left `print(phone_book)` in the main body of the loop, meaning that it will be executed with every cycle of the loop, if you just want it to be printed once the dictionary has been populated, you should put it outside of the loop.

```
phone_book = {}

while True:
    name = input("Enter a name: ")

    if name in phone_book:
        print(phone_book[name])
    elif name == "":
        break
    else:
        phone_number = input("Enter a phone number in the following format[(123)456-7890)]: ")
        phone_book[name] = phone_number

print(phone_book)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the print out of the loop. I changed the code around a little too just for an example.

```
phone_book_new = {}


def phone():
    while True:
        name = input('Name: ')
        number = int(input('Number: '))
        phone_book = {name: number}
        phone_book_new.update(phone_book)
        break


phone()
print(phone_book_new)
```